# Is the following statement is True/false?$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the  following statement is True/false  ?

A continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if it maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

i thinks  its true  take  take  $f(x) = x$

Comment: Regarding your reasoning to argue it should be true: a single example is not a proof! (It can be a counterexample ($\exists$ statement), not show a $\forall$ statement holds...)

Comment: Possible diuplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709626/uniform-continuity-of-a-function-and-cauchy-sequences?rq=1